# Edit ignored while said to be peer reviewed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, code-review-se

I'm trying to correct the indentation and some typos of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/if-statement-problem). The problem is, after editing, the text

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

appears but the edit is not send to the review queue (the number of suggested edits stay at 0). Seems like an important bug (I have only 156 rep on CodeReview, but I don't think this really matters), frustrating when you just spent several minutes fixing a question for nothing... What can I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no bug. Your first suggested edit [was rejected](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6150). The second one at this moment [has one approval vote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6151).

Comment: Thank for the links. How do I get to the page you pointed first ? And why is the reason for reject not shown (because when I reject edits on SO, I have to choose a reason) ?

Comment: If you go to your profile, you can find it within your [list of activities](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/19519/synxis?tab=activity). Given that the Community User has taken the blame for the first rejection, either there was a collision with an edit from the OP or your suggestion has been improved but marked as "not helpful". Given the edit by the OP, the first scenario is most likely the cause.

Comment: Surely a collision for the first (the OP edited the question after me). Thank you for your help, +1 +accepted

Comment: @Bart: It has to be a collision. Users who improve the post are now listed on the suggested edit with an "Edit" action, whether they mark it as helpful or not.

Comment: @animuson Ah, thanks for that heads-up. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see your own suggestions.
Even if you are able to see the suggested edits, which depends from the type of the Stack Exchange sites (i.e. private beta, beta, or graduated site) and from your reputation there, you cannot see your own suggested edits in the review queue, and approve them.